# Need working example how to run MS Access macro from Windows shortcut (NOT AutoExec)

Tags: ms-access, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make the MS Access command-line parameter /x work. How do I FULLY specify in the command line the macro's location IN the Access database? I'm NOT trying to do an AUTOEXEC setup.

The database opens but keeps giving me  "macro not found" errors.  I've tried variations after the /x command, including things that match "examples" on the Web but none work. I've tried it as both a Sub and a Function.

I also tried setting up a RunCode macro named Show_Msg and I get the same "can't find" error message with that. I tried the full path with both periods and bangs and neither worked.

I'm pretty much sure the problem is that I need to specify the FULL path WITHIN Access, i.e., Project, Module, Sub/Function.

Windows Command line:
`"F:\CLIENT DOWNLOADS\TDN\TXE_DEN.accdb" /x z_show_msgbox`

Trying to run:

```
Function z_show_msgbox() _
            As Variant

    ' denImport.z_show_msgbox

    MsgBox "JUST TO SEE HOW TO RUN A SUB" _
        & "DIRECTLY FROM WINDOWS"

    z_show_msgbox = True
End Function
```

Project: TXE_DEN
Module: denImport

I expect the specified database to open (which it does) and run the sub or function or macro.

When /x has the sub/function name the error message is:

> Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'z_show_msgbox.' If
>   'z_show_msgbox' is a new macro or macro group, make sure you have
>   saved it and that you have typed its name correctly.

I get a similar error when /x has the macro name instead of the function.

Comment: I tested this calling a general macro and it works, even when macro calls function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I had tried the macro approach too but that didn't work either.

The problem was that I had the macro code set up as:

Function: z_show_msg

(no following parentheses)

When I changed that to

Function: z_show_msg()

it now works.

I had created the macro but didn't test it because it's only one command and I knew the function worked.

With the macro properly set up this works:

"F:\CLIENT DOWNLOADS\TDN\TXE_DEN.accdb" /x Show_Msg